# ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format error in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a function takes time as an argument and return the time of the day as follow:

```
def time_of_day(time):
    #time = str(time) + ':00:00'
    time = pd.to_timedelta(time)
    if (time >= pd.to_timedelta('5:00:00')) & (time <= pd.to_timedelta('9:00:00')):
        return 'Morning'
    elif (time > pd.to_timedelta('9:00:00')) & (time <= pd.to_timedelta('16:00:00')):
        return 'Day'
    elif (time > pd.to_timedelta('16:00:00')) & (time <= pd.to_timedelta('22:00:00')):
        return 'Evening'
    else:
        return 'Night'
```

I have a dataframe which contains the time column and dataframe looks like below:

df:

```
Month   Season  time
                                        
1       Summer  00:05:00
1       Summer  00:35:00
1       Summer  01:05:00
1       Summer  01:35:00
1       Summer  02:05:00
```

the data type of data frame is:

```
Month         int64
Season       object
time         object
```

When I apply the function to the column `df['time'].apply(time_of_day)`, I got following error:

```
ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format
```

I am not sure where I made the mistake. Could anyone help me in rectifying the issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce, [it runs here](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/8392f4f9.py). It's likely you have some data in `time` column that doesn't match the `hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: @Psidom I reduced my data size to five rows. But still, I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you post the five rows that failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think data are python object times, so need convert them to strings:

```
df['time'].astype(str).apply(time_of_day)
```